# Retrieve Performance Counter's "Explain Text"

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, performancecounter, query-performance

How can  I get a Performance counter's `Explain Text`'s string value thru Powershell.

[image]

I thought it would be a property of a counter

`Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"|gm`

`(Get-Counter '\logicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk Queue Length').countersamples|gm`

But it isn't. I found [`Lodctr /q`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490926.aspx) to query the counters and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372613%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, I can't find exactly how to get the string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with calling .net framework objects you have access to all the methods provided by [PerformanceCounterCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The following should help you get started:

```
$categoryName = "Processor"
$categoryInstance = "_Total"
$counterName = "% Processor Time"

# Call the static method to get the Help for the category
$categoryHelp = [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::GetCategories() | ?{$_.CategoryName -like $categoryName} | select -expandproperty  CategoryHelp

# Create an instance so that GetCounters() can be called
$pcc = new-object System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory($categoryName)
$counterHelp = $pcc.GetCounters($categoryInstance) | ?{$_.CounterName -like $counterName} | select -expandproperty CounterHelp

$categoryHelp 
$counterHelp
```